# Compare button value

Tags: objective-c

I have two buttons in my view.

```
[button1 setBackgroundImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button2 setBackgroundImage:image2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

How can I compare two images in these buttons? I'de tried:

```
if (button1.imageView.image.CGImage == button2.imageView.image.CGImage)
{
   NSLog(@"equal");
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"not equal");
}
```

It doesn't work :(.

any advice?
thanks for Help
Yayo

Comment: what do you mean by compare.. do you want to see if they are the same image, the same image contents what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if ([[button1 backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[button2 backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal]])
```